# metterci impegno

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

I understand this sentence

> Vi chiedo di metterci impegno.

as

> I ask you to dedicate some efforts here. (for instance a task has been given, I ask you to dedicate some effort to this particular task.)

Is this correct, or what nuance brings "ci" in metterci ? Is metterci impegno a fixed expression ? How would you translate or understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a fixed expression.

My understanding is that `ci` in this context is a demonstrative pronoun that stands for `in ciò` = "in this" (rather than an adverb, like "here").

```
Vi chiedo di metterci impegno.
```

is equivalent to

```
Vi chiedo di mettere impegno in questa cosa.
```

My literal translation would be "I ask you to put effort in this" but a more natural translation could simply be "Please, put in some effort".

Comment: Is Vi chiedo di metterci impegno. correct italian at all then?

Comment: Yes, completely correct.